# $.ajax textstatus shows success but database is not updated?Jquery php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mariadb

I am trying to insert something into a database. I invoked php to $.ajax. The textstatus shows 'Success' but how come the table still returns zero result?Need help really bad. Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="reg">
<form id="regform" name="regform" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<label id="name_error" for="name" class="error">Enter Your Complete Name.</label><br/>
<input type='submit' name="Submit Name" class="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function() {
 $('.error').hide();
 $(".submit").click(function() {
    $('.error').hide();

    var name= $("input#name").val();
    if(name==""){
       $("label#name_error").show();
       $("input#name").focus();
       return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/folder1/folder2/reg.php";
      sync: false,
      data: {name:name},

      success: function(data, textStatus){
       //alert(data);
   document.getElementById('reg').innerHTML = data + textStatus;
      },
      error: function(jqXHR){
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
  }
     });
     return false;
    });
 });
```

**PHP/reg.php**

```
<?php
include "dbcon.php";
$name=$_POST['name'];

$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO regtable ('name'), VALUES('$name')") or die();
if($query){
echo "1";
}else{
echo "2";
}
?>
```

Comment: Take the comma out of the query.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `$_POST` value without sanitising it first. I'd recommend updating your current code to use PHP's PDO - here's a good tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your SQL syntax, you should remove te "," before VALUES.

If that doesn't work check MySQL errors with `mysql_query("QUERY") or die(myql_error());`

Comment: owww..thanks, cant believe i missed that. wasted 2 hours of my life.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax call will return success even if your query is not executed.

Please replace this code

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO regtable ('name'), VALUES('$name')") or die();
```

with

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO regtable (`name`) VALUES('$name')") or die();
```